# Deep paging on facet results

Tags: solr

According to https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Faceting I can use  `facet.offset` and `facet.limit` to paginate.

I think these are analogous to `start` and `rows` for normal query results.

However, wouldn't this be very slow if I have too many facet results? According to https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Pagination+of+Results:

> When you wish to fetch a very large number of sorted results from Solr
>   to feed into an external system, using very large values for the start
>   or rows parameters can be very inefficient.  Pagination using start
>   and rows not only require Solr to compute (and sort) in memory all of
>   the matching documents that should be fetched for the current page,
>   but also all of the documents that would have appeared on previous
>   pages.

So for deep paging on normal queries, I'd use a `cursorMark` instead.

So

1) Am I right that deep paging on facet results using `facet.offset` has the same performance conerns as the quote above?

2) Is there something like `cursorMark` or other more efficient deep paging for facet results instead of `facet.offset`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you will take a look into one of the `FacetCollector` implementation, you will see something like this:

```
@Override
  public boolean collect(BytesRef term, int count) {
    if (count > min) {
      // NOTE: we use c>min rather than c>=min as an optimization because we are going in
      // index order, so we already know that the keys are ordered.  This can be very
      // important if a lot of the counts are repeated (like zero counts would be).
      spare.copyUTF8Bytes(term);
      queue.add(new SimpleFacets.CountPair<>(spare.toString(), count));
      if (queue.size()>=maxsize) min=queue.last().val;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

and a little bit above:

```
maxsize = limit>0 ? offset+limit : Integer.MAX_VALUE-1;
```

which basically leads to the same problem as for deep paging. The code will create a huge `BoundedTreeSet` (cause `maxsize` is determined by sum of offset and limit), and complexity will be around the same as in deep paging scenario.

However, most of the time, I do not expect anybody to have array of facet values larger than 10_000 (got it from the top of my head, probably even less), which shouldn't cause any troubles (until you get millions of facet values).

Usually facets are coming from fields with limited semantics (brand, color, state, department, etc.) and usually these values are limited.

As a summary: algorithm is the same as in collecting matched documents, but the nature of the facet values should save us from the problem.